# Running average issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, moving-average

if you can give me any hint on this question I would surely appreciate it. How can I start it, any idea?

I am running a software which generates energies. I have N time steps (blocks) and in each time step it generates several lines. First column is the a counter for number of generated lines in each time step. Therefore, I will have a text file like below one, it is a simplified example of a huge file:

```
#Block:           3           3           0
           1        -0.3746468365E+04         0.9420348015E+00        -0.3745526330E+04         0.1636348407-151       316.8679         0.2626532250-312
           2        -0.3746707738E+04         0.1149418891E+01        -0.3745558319E+04         0.1220432713E+00       386.6247         0.2626532250-312
           3        -0.3746757823E+04         0.1195378991E+01        -0.3745562444E+04         0.1636348407-151       402.0841         0.2626532250-312
#Block:           4           4           1
           1        -0.3746625102E+04         0.6261182789E+00        -0.3745998983E+04         0.1636348407-151       210.6045         0.2626532250-312
           2        -0.3746723956E+04         0.7190568481E+00        -0.3746004899E+04         0.1636348407-151       241.8658         0.2626532250-312
           3        -0.3746758909E+04         0.7514702248E+00        -0.3746007439E+04         0.1636348407-151       252.7685         0.2626532250-312
           4        -0.3746707738E+04         0.7067911904E+00        -0.3746000947E+04        -0.3205844292E+00       237.7401         0.2626532250-312
           5        -0.3746680579E+04         0.6897161187E+00        -0.3745990863E+04         0.1636348407-151       231.9966         0.2626532250-312

#Block:           5           5           1
           1        -0.3746625102E+04         0.6261182789E+00        -0.3745998983E+04         0.1636348407-151       210.6045         0.2626532250-312
           2        -0.3746723956E+04         0.7190568481E+00        -0.3746004899E+04         0.1636348407-151       241.8658         0.2626532250-312
           3        -0.3746758909E+04         0.7514702248E+00        -0.3746007439E+04         0.1636348407-151       252.7685         0.2626532250-312
           4        -0.3746707738E+04         0.7067911904E+00        -0.3746000947E+04        -0.3205844292E+00       237.7401         0.2626532250-312
           5        -0.3746680579E+04         0.6897161187E+00        -0.3745990863E+04         0.1636348407-151       231.9966         0.2626532250-312
```

I want to calculate the running average of the column #3 of these data and save in a "average text file". Therefore,

- the first value in the text file should be the average of the column #3 of block 1. 
  (first 3 values= (3.5+7.1+5.4)/3)
- the second value in the text file should be the average of the column #3 of block 1 and block 2. 
  (first 8 values= (3.5+7.1+5.4+2.5+1.1+5.4+4.4+1.4)/8)
- the third value in the text file should be the average of the column #3 of block 1 and block 2 and block 3. 
  (first 12 values= (3.5+7.1+5.4+2.5+1.1+5.4+4.4+1.4+3.5+1.1+8.1+9.4)/12)
- I have N blocks. Actually I am calculating the average of the column #3 of all blocks as function of time step.

Here is what I have tried

```
with open('xxx.txt','r') as file:

 groups = [] # Will contain the final data

 current_group = [] # Temporary
 line = file.readline()
 while line != "":
    if line.startswith("#Block"):
        # Store the current group and start a new one
        groups.append(current_group)
        current_group = []
    else:
        # Add the number to the current group
        current_group.append(float(line.split()[2]))
    line = file.readline()
    averages = list() 
    for i in xrange(len(groups)):
      flatten_list = list(itertools.chain(*groups[:i+1]))
      print (flatten_list)
      averages.append(sum(flatten_list) / len(flatten_list))
    with open('output.txt', 'a+') as output_f:
      output_f.writelines(averages)
```

Comment: I tried but I really dont know how to make the file. I updated the question

Comment: Please add `python-3.x` to tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED TO Python 3 AND NEW INPUT**

```
import itertools

history = []

with open('sample.txt') as f:
    group = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if 'Block' in line:
            if group:
                history.append(group)
                group = []
        elif line:
            group.append(float(line.split()[2]))

    history.append(group)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(len(history)):
        l = list(itertools.chain(*history[:i+1]))
        print(sum(l) / len(l), file=f)
```

And output:

```
$ cat output.txt 
1.0956108945
0.84749816805
0.790241385023077
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 7, in <module>
    print("({}) / {} = {}".format(' + '.join(str(n) for n in history), len(history), sum(history) / len(history)))
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: @AlirezaBahrami I don't get that traceback using Python 2.7. Also I updated the answer to comply more with your code.

Comment: if '#Block' in line:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @AlirezaBahrami Oh, python3.

Comment: Could you please test your code with the new table in the question?

Comment: when I try your code with full text file it gives me error.  Can you please check the table in the question? witth the real number

Comment: @AlirezaBahrami Checked with the new table.

Comment: is it possible to print it like a column not in a row?

Comment: @AlirezaBahrami Not sure what you mean. It is currently written as a single column to the file.

Comment: with the new table ... it also add the value in the #block row. for exasmple:#Block:           3           3           0 ;

Comment: the first value in the output is the summation of: -0.3746468365E+04  + -0.3746707738E+04 + -0.3746757823E+04

Comment: if you calculate these numebr the average is different

Answer (score 0):

You are going good so far, as you have managed to extract 3rd column of each block as a list in `groups` list, now, after your `while` loop you can do

```
averages = list() 
for i in range(len(groups)):
    flatten_list = list(itertools.chain(*groups[:i+1]))
    print flatten_list
    averages.append(sum(flatten_list) / len(flatten_list))
with open('output.txt', 'a+') as output_f:
    output_f.writelines(averages)
```

Full code will be

```
with open('xxx.txt','r') as file:

 groups = [] # Will contain the final data

 current_group = [] # Temporary
 line = file.readline()
 while line != "":
    if line.startswith("#Block"):
        # Store the current group and start a new one
        groups.append(current_group)
        current_group = []
    else:
        # Add the number to the current group
        current_group.append(float(line.split()[2]))
    line = file.readline()
    averages = list() 
 for i in range(len(groups)):
   flatten_list = list(itertools.chain(*groups[:i+1]))
   print (flatten_list)
   averages.append(sum(flatten_list) / len(flatten_list))
 with open('output.txt', 'a+') as output_f:
   output_f.writelines(averages)
```

Comment: @AlirezaBahrami you are probably getting error at this line `current_group.append(int(line.split()[2]))` as you are converting the 3rd column value to `int` whereas it is float, so you need to convert it to `float` i.e. `current_group.append(float(line.split()[2]))`. Other that that, your code seems fine.

Comment: current_group.append(float(line.split()[2]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Do your new block starts with "Block" line or "#Block N" line?

Comment: If it starts with "#Block N" then your line `if line == "Block":` is wrong, you need to change it with `if line.startswith("#Block"):`.

Comment: If it starts with "Block" and you are still getting this error, that means your file structure is not corrupt, you are getting a malformed line which does not look like `1      2     1.5      1.1`.

Comment: It start like other blocks ... all blocks start with # . I updated the question code. is it what you mean? I got still error:     for i in xrange(len(groups)):
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

Comment: Ok, this error means you are working with Python3, you need to replace `xrange` with `range` for it work with Python3. Edited my answer.

Comment: Also you need to put my code after your while loop not inside your while loop. Let me add full code to the answer.

Comment: I am confused:     for i in xrange(len(groups)):
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

Comment: `xrange` was used in Python2, it was replaced in Python3 wit `range`, so, replace `xrage` with `range` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Input file name is 'input.txt'.
Output file name is 'result.txt'.

```
with open('INPUT.TXT', 'r') as fout:
  lst_of_num=[]
  for line in fout:

    if line[0]=='#':
      #print line
      if lst_of_num:
        #print sum(lst_of_num) / float(len(lst_of_num))
        with open("result.txt", "a+") as myfile:
          myfile.write(str(sum(lst_of_num) / float(len(lst_of_num)))+'\n')
        #lst_of_num=[]
    else:
      lst_of_num.append(float(line.split()[2]))

  with open("result.txt", "a+") as myfile:
        myfile.write(str(sum(lst_of_num) / float(len(lst_of_num)))+'\n')
```

Comment: print line, just stop here

Comment: any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @AlirezaBahrami Now Try the new code I make it python 3 compatible.
I am compiling with python 2.7

Comment: thanks. But it only gives the average for first 2 blocks

Comment: @AlirezaBahrami Try new code First delete the result.txt and then check the result.text

Comment: when I try your code with full txt file it gives me only one number. Can you check the table in the question?

Comment: the code works well but for a longer table it did  not work. could you please check the table in the question?